# Out of memory error Java heap space - with ImageIO

Tags: java, image, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, javax.imageio

I'm using ImageIO.read(InputStream is) in loop for making BufferedImages from Remote Server (HttpConnection and InputStream)

but, It happens out of memory java heap space everytime.

I don't know why this happens.

This is my jvm parameter option.

**-verbosegc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xmx1024m - XX:PermSize=128m**

and full gc logs.

```
[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 506K->0K(6656K)] [PSOldGen: 963K->1457K(5504K)] 1469K-
>1457K(12160K) [PSPermGen: 8556K->8556K(131072K)], 0.0155080 secs]

[Full GC [PSYoungGen: 480K->0K(11072K)] [PSOldGen: 5001K->4697K(11456K)]
5481K->4697K(22528K) [PSPermGen: 18222K->18222K(131072K)], 0.0350780 
5481K->secs]
```

as you see there are free space in younggen and oldgen, permgen. That is a last full gc log.

After logging, jvm shutdown with out of memory.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.getData(ICC_Profile.java:1315)
        at java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.getInstance(ICC_Profile.java:762)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.setImageData(JPEGImageReader.java:610)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:561)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(JPEGImageReader.java:316)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(JPEGImageReader.java:438)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:554)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:940)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:924)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1322)
```

Please help. Thanks.

I'm sorry for my question.

I have posted my source.
It extract hashcode from images.

1.main codes.

```
HashExtractor h = new HashExtractor();
while(rs.next()) {
   Inputstream is = getStream(); 
   h.doSomething(is);
   //something to do using bi.
   is.close();
}

//in HashExtractor
public String doSomething(InputStream is) {
   BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(is);
   String hash = "";
   //extract hash.  

   return hash;
}
```

I have removed some details to looks easy. (getting connection.. etc)

Thanks!

Comment: *"Please help."*  Please ask a question.  I can think of 6 questions that might be asked based on your experience.  Choose one.  You might also want to add the detail of whether the code is keeping references to earlier images or only references one at a time, as well as the size of images in terms of WxH and bit depth.

Comment: Could you post your relevant section of the code? Or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) version of your code? That would really help us help you!

Comment: I have posted my source codes. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a "here's my code so far, now do my job for me" site.

Comment: I didn't ask "do my job for me"...
If you have feel like that I apologize..
I think so many lines in this question, I cutted out some lines.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of all that manipulation of the `BufferedImage` after you read it, get an `ImageReader` for it and use an `ImageReadParam` to set the render size, and whatever else you can persuade it to do while it is reading the image. That way you don't end up with multiple copies of the image in memory.

Comment: Thanks! I have found ImageReader example.

Comment: Do you have any examples for it? Thank you in advance